# How can I delete a login account on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, login

I have a new email address, and it has been updated on one of the Stack Exchange "communities". I use the Stack Exchange account to log in to the "communities" I use, such as this one: Stack Overflow. How can I delete the old email address?

Now I have two logins for Stack Exchange and want to eliminate the old one. Also, I want to make sure future notifications from all "communities" come to my new email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage login accounts in

https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/me

You can manage contact preferences in

https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me

Answer (score 0):

Go into your account by clicking the profile picture next to the reputation and badges in the top right corner. Below the site title, there are a few tabs including, "Profile", "Activity" and "Settings". Click on the "Settings" tab. To the left there is a sidebar, click the menu that says, "My Logins". In the area to the right, you can remove, edit and add any logins to any sites.